# Object resetting when blender is restarted

Tags: mesh, objects

So I'm making a render, I started to replace some objects with an updated version AKA I made a change to one object. And duplicated that object. And had it be the same loc and rot of other objects.(The objects are the exact same). I had saved the file (NOT rendered). When I reopened it, all the objects moved into their first position.

Blender only has one recovered last session and autosave for this file, and they are the same as the main one. Can someone help me fix this?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgoqWO2KVpY&feature=youtu.be <---VID OF PROBLEM

Comment: Fix what exactly? What is "*replace some objects with an updated version*"? What did you replace, the datablocks? What does "*moved into their first position*" mean? Did their shape change back, did they move in the scene? What objects, how? Your question is pretty vague, please edit it and provide more details and screenshots of what you mean.

Comment: Remember that we're here to help, we don't mean to discourage people, but on stack exchange we have high standards for questions. Just edit your question, add more details, and don't be vague, we'll help if we can.

Comment: I added more detail and a video not screenshot

Comment: Your objects are most likely animated, the yellow name in the bottom left corner indicate it is keyframed most likely for position, rotation or scale. You moved them but the position is keyframed, so on reopening/animating they revert to the keyframed positions. Either clear the keyframes or keyframe the new positions.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you describe are consistent with failing to apply modifications of scale, location, and location after moving the object. It is a good habit to get into to apply these (using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>) after every event that changes the location, size or rotation.

Comment: No I don't think that is it, the object seems to be keyframed. Also you should not be blindingly applying transforms to objects, especially ones used multiple times in a scene. It will screw up their object centers, and move other instances.